# Checking if time is within a set of start and end times

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am trying to figure out if a certain time lies with a set of start and end times for every id between 2 different tables

For example there are 2 tables Table_A and Table_B

Table A schema Looks like this

`ID |  timestamp | status` - This holds information for every unit of time (say every minute)

Table B schema looks like this

`ID | Start_timestamp | End_timestamp` - However there are multiple entries for every ID for the same date.

I want to figure out if timestamp in Table_A lies between any of the start_timestamp or end_timestamps in Table_B

Expected results

Table_A

```
ID | timestamp | status
1  | 300       | ABC
1  | 600       | ABC
1  | 900       | ABC
1  | 1200      | DEF
...
```

Table_B

```
ID | Start_timestamp | End_timestamp
1  | 100             | 400 
1  | 700             | 1000
```

Output

```
ID | timestamp | status | Flag
1  | 300       | ABC    | True
1  | 600       | ABC    | False
1  | 900       | ABC    | True
1  | 1200      | DEF    | False
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a `left join` and conditional aggregation.

```
select a.id,a.timestamp,a.status
,max(case when a.timestamp between b.start_time and b.end_time then 'True' else 'False' end) as t_f_flag
from tblA a
left join tblB b on a.id = b.id 
group by a.id,a.timestamp,a.status
```